# Retrieving data from column names stored in an array - mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have an array with a list of column names in it. I want to retrieve data from the columns in a database table by getting the column names from my array. I have tried the following but I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass:
```

My code:

```
       while($row = $dateResult->fetch_object()) {

            echo "<tr>";
            for($k=0; $k<count($collumnNames); $k++) {

                echo "<td>";                    
                echo $row->$collumnNames[$k];           
                echo "</td>";

            }
            echo "</tr>";

        }
```

Comment: What exactly is `$columnNames`? You probably want `$row->{$collumnNames[$k]}` instead.

Comment: $collumnNames is an array of strings where each string is a column name in the database table

Comment: why not then just do `foreach ($row as $key => $val)`?